# How do I use EJS to check if an element ID exists on the page?

Tags: javascript, ejs

What is the best way to check if an element exists on a page with EJS. The following doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
<% if(document.getElementById('modal-open')) { %>
  <div>Modal is Open</div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: ejs renders to html, besides, to be looking to see if modal is open you should be using the events which bootstrap fires like `$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {` or `myModalEl.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {` in bs5, rtm: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#events

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's your usecases, but EJS should not run on the browser, usually it only run on the build process or on the server side.

Means you have no access to the DOM. You can not use syntax that rely on the DOM like `document`, `window`, and any other DOM API.

The best way is to do it is on the script block (JavaScript) which will be executed on the browser.

In your cases, I suggest to just render the DOM first from EJS with additional CSS hidden elements:

```html
<div id="someid">Modal is show</div>
```

```css
.someId {
    display: none;
}
```

Then you can toggle it in your JavaScript based on your logic

```js
if (document.getElementById('modal-open')) {
    // Show the id 'someid' using JavaScript syntax
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should compare,

```
<% if(document.querySelector('#modal-open') !== null) { %> //the value will be
// true if it exists or false, if it isn't.
  <div>Modal is Open</div>
<% } %>
```

I think it should work